# Big endian : moves between two registers of the same size

Tags: memory, move, endianness

If a DSP has two CPU registers of the same size, say A and B, both are 16 bits ( 2 bytes)
if I do the following instruction:

move A,B

I have 2 questions:

1. So does the lower byte of A move into the higher byte of B?
2. Does Endianess only come into picture when we are dealing with memory locations that is different in size than the register from or to which the move is being made?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you `move` is a 16-bit move, the lower byte of B will go into the lower byte of A and the higher byte of B will go into the higher byte of A. Why should it be any different?
2. Yes, as long as both locations have the same size you do a verbatim bit-by-bit copy and don't care about endianess.